# Service with low connection overhead

Tags: java, web-services, http, service, rpc

I building a service that does real time computations on text such as tweets.  this will be called by fixed number of clients.  However, the issue I see is, if I setup the service as webservice, the overhead of making and breaking HTTP connections will be high.

What options exists today that can reduce the overhead (by persistant connections or otherwise)? Please excuse if the description is not sufficient.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Websockets could be a good solution for your problem, it's a lightweight standard that it's well supported nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

> the overhead of making and breaking HTTP connections will be high

You are mistaken. The overhead of making and breaking HTTP connections is at worst no higher than the overhead of making or breaking TCP connections, and it is ameliorated considerably by HTTP keep-alive.